# Ember js - Trigger click event on other element on button click

Tags: ember.js

**My Requirement:** I am using a custom tab component which has 3-4 tabs and there is next previous buttons on tab. I want to switch tabs when clicked on next, previous buttons.

**My Approach:** I was trying to trigger a click event on tab when clicked on next button like generally when we click a tab the associated tab content shows.

I can do the same with jquery but how can we do this in ember? I am using **ember 2.16**. Can someone help with this or can suggest is there a better way to achieve the requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
My-component.hbs

<ul class="my-tabs">

   <li class="{{if tabs.firstTab 'active' ''}}" {{action 'switchTab' 'firstTab'}}>Tab1</li>
   <li class="{{if tabs.secondTab 'active' ''}}" {{action 'switchTab' 'secondTab'}}>Tab2
   </li>

</ul>
{{#if tabs.firstTab}}
   //content for first tab
{{/if}}
{{#if tabs.secondTab}}
   //content for second tab
{{/if}}
```

My-component.js

```
tabs:{
  firstTab:false,
  secondTab:false,

},
actions:{

  switchTab(currentTab){
     this.get('tabs').setProperties({
       firstTab:false,
       secondTab:false
     });
     this.get('tab').set(''+currentTab,true);

  }

}
```

You can do something like this.
If you do not want to have variable `tabs` then use javascript to add a class to current clicked tab and remove existing active tab.
Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: see my template is like this - https://jsfiddle.net/sajal_das/y1n4hotL/. plz check and help with appropriate sol. I am new to ember. And i have next previous buttons, which when clicked the tabs should switch.

Comment: Do you have tabs and prev next btn as well or You have only prev and next?
Can't see any next and prev btn in your template

Comment: yes in that i did not added the buttons. But in actual template there its normal tab + buttons also. Let me update the fiddle with prev next buttons code.

Comment: and i have put the whole tab in one component. Means there is a tab component and then there are child components for each tab content. I am trying to set class as property but its working for only same component. How can i set property of other component (2nd tab class property from 1st tab action on next button)

Comment: any specific reason for two different component?

Comment: just to separate things and reduce confussion ..  and each tab has its different functionality so thatswhy. How can we change property of one component from action of another component ?

Comment: check your fiddle now. You will need to add a var as a flag to your components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158403/discussion-between-sajal-and-sandeep).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to make different tabs know which one is active, create a tab object:

`Ember.Object.extend({
  activeTab: null,
  tabId: null,
  isActive: Ember.computed('activeTab', 'tabId', function(){
    return this.get('activeTab.tabId') === this.get('tabId');
  })
})`

and then in your controller, create your tabs and pass them all a reference to the active tab. You update active tab both when the buttons are clicked, and in some order as next/previous buttons are clicked. On change of the active tab, all buttons fire that computed property, asking if they are active, and one will be.

You could also avoid computed properties and simply go iterate through each of the tabs and update the `isActive` property by the same logic as mentioned in the computed property above:

`this.get('tabs').forEach(function(tab){
    tab.set('isActive', tab.tabId === self.get('ctrl.activeTab.tabId'));
});`

Comment: yeah i already did with this approach. But still did not got something for trigerring a click. In my other requirement i am using bootstrap modal, where currently i have used $('#element').modal('show'). Searching solution for this.

Comment: if you put together a ember twiddle with the bare minimum parts, I'm sure we could figure it out :)

Comment: Other than this i have few more questions what i need to clear conceptually. I am very new to ember and i want to understand the best practices and data flow structure which i cannot ask here as its not for that purpose. Can u send your email or create chat link or any other medium where i can ask u those things ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159498/sajal-ember-js-trigger-click-event-on-other-element-on-button-click